# Is it possible to list all files which have local changes in IntelliJ IDEA (outside of "Changes" view)

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA offers two very handy actions as part of the "View" menu: "Recent Files" and "Recently Changed Files". Is there a way to only list the files which have local changes? (In a non-intrusive style like the actions above do, **not** as part of the "Changes" view)

Comment: What's wrong with the Changes view?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but for the purpose of navigation I would prefer a more light-weight popup (without the changelist structure and file path decorations, but with type icons).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

2020.1 and later versions have an [option to use the new non-modal](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap7/#commit_tool_window_commit_dialog) **Commit** tool-window:

[image: non-modal]

If you enable this option, the local changes will be in the **Commit** tool window.

Previous IDE versions have the following ways to view modified files:

- [Local changes tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-changes-tab.html) (`View` | `Tool Windows` | `Version Control` - `Local Changes`), default shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.
- [Changed files Scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhahj.png) in the Project view

Previously the only way to view the changed files was via the Commit dialog:

`Version Control` | `Commit Changes` will show a dialog with locally changed files.

Comment: Thank you -- I am using this as a work-around, constantly afraid that I will hit the `Commit` button by mistake ;-)

Comment: It is also possible to show the Changes view as a nice little popup.

Right Click on the Changes tab and select "Floating Mode".

Comment: Cmd + 9 for mac users.

Comment: That option isn't available in 2020.1. I can't really find the local changes in this version...

Comment: @Tharkius see the updated answer. Did you enable the option for the non-modal commit interface?

Comment: I am able to see the files which are changed by just unchecking the "Use non-model commit interface" checkbox.

Comment: Ugh. I seem to have clicked that non-modal checkbox at some point, and then my familiar view of Local Changes went away. It was terribly annoying

Answer (score 31):

You can go on the Project Pane, and find the option

```
 View as > Scope > Changed Files
```

It will show a tree with only the modified files.

Comment: If you can't find where "View as" is, as I couldn't, simply use Cmd+Shift+E, you then can see all recently changed files.

Comment: @ZinanXing that works well indeed, can select all modified files and hit enter, boom! 

Comment: can't find it any more in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3

Answer (score 22):

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> (in MacOS X <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>) you can get a panel with the changed files

Comment: Dude posting brand [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243583/is-it-possible-to-list-all-files-which-have-local-changes-in-intellij-idea-outs/21844723#21844723) with the same content aren't acceptable!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing anyone answering the same thing as me in this question.

Comment: As its an exact duplicate, you should post it as a comment over the question rather than answer.

Comment: Exact duplicate of what? I don't see any mention of Alt+9 anywhere else other than in my answer.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, and in my opinion it is the most correct and accurate answer to the question.  It literally shows the "local changes" tab which the poster asked for with just one combined keypress. Thank you! PS: here is a link to the feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/local-changes-tab.html

Comment: Cmd + 9 for mac users.

Comment: After `Cmd + 9` you can `Cmd + A` and `Enter` to open all modified files

Comment: BTW, the `Alt + 9` reference in CrazyCoder's answer was added some time after I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 11):

With 2020.2, you can view the local change list with the tab "commit" on your left (keystroke alt+0):
[image]

Comment: Note that any new files which were not yet added to git will not be shown there. But it is definitly useful for many cases. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using version control tools (git, svn), click on the `module directory`, right click and select "`Local History` - `Show History`", all file changes will be listed.

Answer (score 0):

Press cmd + E ( ⌘E ios ) or Ctrl+E ( windows ) and mark "show edited only" box, then you can see only edited files.